# wsgi.url_scheme http in docker using nginx

Tags: django, docker, apache, nginx, gunicorn

I am using Apache on CentOS. On this server I have a Django project with docker. There are two containers in docker (nginx and python).

In the Apache I have .conf that have proxy to nginx container that is exposed on port 803. SSL is set in the Apache conf as well.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Scheme "https"
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:803/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:803/
```

On the docker I have app.conf for nginx that looks like this:

```
upstream project {
    server project-python:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name _;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    client_max_body_size 64M;

    location / {
        gzip_static on;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme "https";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol "ssl";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl=on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://project;

        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

In the Dockerfile Python is exposed on port 5000 and in the docker-compose.prod.yml file for production the python is started with gunicorn with this command:

`gunicorn project.wsgi:application --preload --bind 0.0.0.0:5000`
So I have two issues.

In the Django when I dump request.META I got `wsgi.url_scheme` that is `http`.

The second one is that I don't even understand how nginx is communicating with gunicorn because when I set app.conf to be just like below it is working also. How the nginx know that Python is exposed on port 5000.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name _;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    client_max_body_size 64M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://project;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  project-python:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/python/Dockerfile
    container_name: project-python
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www:rw
      - .aws:/home/www/.aws

  project-nginx:
    build:
      context: docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: project-nginx
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:803:80"
    depends_on:
      - project-python
```

docker-compose.prod.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  project-python:
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    command: gunicorn project.wsgi:application --preload --bind 0.0.0.0:5000
    expose:
      - 5000

  project-nginx:
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "production"
      APP_NAME: "project-nginx"
      APP_DEBUG: "False"
      SERVICE_NAME: "project-nginx"
```

Comment: You want to know how to get Django to detect that it's being served behind HTTPS? Nginx "knows" to use port 5000 because it's defined in `upstream project`

Comment: As I said in the last example. Even if I remove this from app.conf it will still work. So there is not upstream in app.conf at all.

Comment: Share your docker-compose.yaml files?

Comment: I have edited question and included docker-compose.yml & docker-compose.prod.yml